# Как откатить не верно выбранный драйвер в ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, драйвер

С помощью GUI был выбран проприетарный драйвер на видео карту nvidia (не тестовый).

Так же, не понимая последствий, был выбран драйвер (*история умалчивает, но в названии было что то про процессор, вторым вариантом было не использовать данное устройство*) для неизвестного устройства.

После перезагрузки системы получили экран выбора пользователя и ввода пароля, но при логине под пользователем либо в гостевом режиме - система думает несколько секунд, затем оба монитора "тухнут" в черный экран на короткое время, а после мы заного получаем экран где предлагается выбрать пользователя.

Можно ли как то откатить?

Comment: Что выдаёт `aptitude search nvidia | grep ^i`?